# SQL sum values from different columns based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Following is the data that i have in a table:

```
Date           Original    Estimated     Actual
2013-04-14     141.44323    NULL          384.875
2013-04-14     31.184295    NULL          200.375
2013-04-14     0            NULL          54.75
2013-04-14     0            NULL          0.625
2013-04-15     5.4326204    NULL          0
2013-04-15     45.795869    NULL          -0.375
2013-04-15     86.57694     NULL          11.875
2013-04-15     186.219      NULL          58.875
```

i want to sum values of column **Actual** but if its value is zero or null then for that specific row value should be taken from **Estimated** column and if **Estimated** column also have zero value then value will be taken from **Original** column. and i want the result to be grouped by Month and year. Please help

Comment: Did you try writing the query to do this?  Please edit your question and show your attempts.

Comment: i was only able to group and sum for one column . i am not able to figure out the combination. do want me to post that?

Comment: You should always post what you tried even if it doesn't work. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, Date) as [Year],
    DATEPART(MONTH, Date) as [Month],
    SUM(COALESCE(NULLIF(Actual,0), NULLIF(Estimated, 0), Original)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, Date), DATEPART(MONTH, Date);
```

Comment: You will probably have to do a case when actual = 0 then null else actuel end for the 3 columns as you want to consider 0 as null :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

<del>SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, Date), DATEPART(MONTH, Date), 
           SUM(Coalesce(Actual, Estimated, Original)) 
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, Date), DATEPART(MONTH, Date);</del>

**Edit** As @MartinSmith pointed out, the `NULL OR Zero` will need to be catered for. This can be done by projecting zero back to NULL with a CTE before running it through the `COALESCE`, like so:

```
   WITH CTE AS
   (
      SELECT 
          CASE WHEN Actual = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Actual END AS Actual,
          CASE WHEN Estimated = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Estimated END AS Estimated,
          CASE WHEN Original = 0 THEN NULL ELSE Original END AS Original
      FROM MyTable
   )
    SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, Date), DATEPART(MONTH, Date), 
           SUM(Coalesce(Actual, Estimated, Original)) 
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY 
       DATEPART(YEAR, Date), DATEPART(MONTH, Date);
```

Comment: +1. `Coalesce(NULLIF(Actual,0), NULLIF(Estimated,0), Original)` would have been more concise though!

Answer (score 0):

NullIf is the best solution as suggestd by Tomas Greif. Corrected code:

```
declare @data table (
    [Date] datetime not null, 
    [Original] decimal(18,9) null, 
    [Estimated] decimal(18,9) null, 
    [Actual] decimal(18,9) null);

insert into @data
    ([Date],           [Original],   [Estimated],    [Actual])
values 
    ('2013-04-14',     141.44323,    NULL,          384.875),
    ('2013-04-14',     31.184295,    NULL,          200.375),
    ('2013-04-14',     0,            NULL,          54.75),
    ('2013-04-14',     0,            NULL,          0.625),
    ('2013-04-15',     5.4326204,    NULL,          0),
    ('2013-04-15',     45.795869,    NULL,          -0.375),
    ('2013-04-15',     86.57694,     NULL,          11.875),
    ('2013-04-15',     186.219,      NULL,          58.875);

select 
    [DateMonth] = dateAdd(month, dateDiff(month, 0, [Date]), 0),
    [SumMonth]  = SUM(COALESCE(NULLIF(Actual,0),NULLIF(Estimated,0),Original))
from @data
group by dateAdd(month, dateDiff(month, 0, [Date]), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using `nullif`? This will be much shorted than `CASE` statement.

```
select 
   DATEPART(YEAR, Date),
   sum(coalesce(nullif(Actual,0),nullif(Estimate,0),Original))
from
   MyTable
group by
   DATEPART(YEAR, Date);
```